# NEST trying to convert enum to string

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Good day:

I have the following code however, I'm getting the following error:

```
return new ConnectionSettings(pool, (s, v) => s.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter())).DefaultIndex(index)
                .DefaultMappingFor<Document>(m => m.IndexName(index).TypeName("doc"))
                .DefaultMappingFor<FacilityType>(m => m.IndexName(index).TypeName("doc"))
                .DefaultMappingFor<Facility>(m => m.IndexName(index).TypeName("doc").RelationName("parent"))
                .BasicAuthentication(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ElasticUser"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ElasticPassword"]);
```

`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'IElasticsearchSerializer' does not contain a definition for 'Converters' and no extension method 'Converters' accepting a first argument of type 'IElasticsearchSerializer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   iserro.API  C:\Users\IEUser\source\repos\iserro-api\iserro.API\App_Start\DiContainerConfig.cs   131 Active`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error message clearly indicates what the problem is.

It looks like you'd like `IElasticsearchSerializer` to be a concrete instance that exposes a `Converters` property, which the [`JsonNetSerializer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html#_jsonnetserializer) type in the [Nest.JsonNetSerializer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST.JsonNetSerializer/) NuGet package exposes so you can hook it up and add custom converters.

Comment: thanks Russ however, when I do this...ElasticSearch is throughing an error because, the serialize string is being sent instead of int (enum index) ===> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse [status]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse [status]","caused_by":{"type":"number_format_exception","reason":"For input string: \"Created\""}},"status":400}

Comment: OK...adding `[Keyword]` to each enum property solved the issue. Now the text for each enum is being indexed.

Comment: Adding `StringEnumConverter` to the list of global converters will cause all enums to be serialized as strings. If that's not what you want, it's probably better to attribute the ones you do want to apply it to.

Comment: There a bug with the converter. Having a type of `PolygonGeoShape` messes up the serialization and cause ElasticSearch to error out. Removing this.